# How to triple integrate a function with variables in limits using Scilab

Tags: integration, scilab

I want to triple integrate a function using Scilab. So while doing it I am inputting variables as limits but I am unable to do it. Please can someone suggest how to integrate a function with variables as its limits.
For example when I try to integrate [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evhOk.png)

I am getting error while using variable as limits. So someone please help me out.

Comment: We need to better understand what you are trying to do. Could you edit your question? Please an example of code that you tried. If possible, add a bit of context of what problem you need to solve using triple integration.

Comment: You can find further information about integration in scilab [here](http://www.tf.uns.ac.rs/~omorr/radovan_omorjan_003_prII/s_examples/Scilab/Gilberto/scilab07.pdf).

Comment: Do you have looked at the int3d function?